# How to plot only one row of a correlation matrix in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the dataframe below, and I would only to plot a portion of the correlation matrix. I would specifically like to plot only the bottom row (correlation between X6 and variables X1-X5). Is there a way to do this using cor.plot? If not, how can I accomplish this? I would like for significance to be displayed on the plot as well.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
cor.plot(df[,c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6")])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#calculate correlation
corx6 <- cor(x = df$X6, y =df[1:5])
corx6

# to show label (X6) in the plot
  rownames(corx6)<-'X6'

# plot correlation matrix

library(corrplot)

corrplot(corx6
         ,addgrid.col = T
         ,type = 'upper'
         ,addCoef.col = T
         ,number.cex = .7
         ,diag = T
         ,tl.cex = .9
         )
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! How would I eliminate those circles altogether surrounding the correlations? Edit: figured it out :)

Comment: If you want to completely remove the color surrounding the correlations, then the color scale is also removed as you do not require color scale of values. In this case you can add :
col = rep(NA, ncol(corx6)) inside the corrplot() function. Hope it could helps.

Comment: Thanks! One last question: How would I go about changing the "1" label on the "y-axis" to "X6" ?

Comment: in this case before running corrplot() , you can rename the rowname:
rownames(corx6)<-'X6'. But you must allow color scale option not to 'NA' in order to show the variables labels.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted an alternative approach to shade the whole cell (similar to `psych::cor.plot()`,  but unlike `corrplot::corrplot()`), you could create an `image` plot (though here, using the `fields` library to add a legend, otherwise replace `fields::image.plot(...)` with `image(...)`):

```
# data 
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
cors <- cor(df[,c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6")])

# plot
fields::image.plot(x = 1:6, y = 1, z = as.matrix(cors[,6]), 
      axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
text(sprintf("%.2f", cors[,6]), x = 1:6, y = 1, col = "white")
axis(1, at = 1:6, label = paste0("X", 1:6), tick = FALSE)
```

[image]